# The command "call npm run build-templates" exited with code 134

Tags: c#, visual-studio, npm

When trying to build my solution in Visual Studio 2017 I get this error message:

```
The command "call npm run build-templates" exited with code 134
```

Looking at the output window I found the following:

```
Installing npm packages for project {project}
 npm WARN No description
 npm WARN No repository field.

 up to date in 12.823s
 Building templates for project {project}

  > build-templates 
  > gulp buildviews

 gulp[14240]: c:\ws\src\node_contextify.cc:640: Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
   1: 00007FF6C923896A v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4554
   2: 00007FF6C91E8956 uv_loop_fork+85542
   3: 00007FF6C91E8A03 uv_loop_fork+85715
   4: 00007FF6C91EEAB8 uv_loop_fork+110472
   5: 00007FF6C984DBFF v8::internal::PassesFilter+847
   6: 00007FF6C984EE37 v8::internal::PassesFilter+5511
   7: 00007FF6C984E0AC v8::internal::PassesFilter+2044
   8: 00007FF6C984DFCB v8::internal::PassesFilter+1819
   9: 000000ACAF550481 
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 134
  npm ERR! build-templates: `gulp buildviews`
  npm ERR! Exit status 134
  npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! Failed at the build-templates script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

error MSB3073: The command "call npm run build-templates" exited with code 134.
```

Comment: you have an npm error while running build-templates share that code.

Comment: I don't know which code is causing the error because the `build-templates` runs every script in the solution, and the output doesn't says the line. It has to be related with my environment because other coworkers don't have the problem. We also have different versions of npm so it is not related to that either.

Comment: might be different gulp version, look at this similar [error](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2171)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by running `npm install gulp` in the project's folder. I do not have much experience with npm so I don't know exactly what it did, but it solved my problem.